# .vbs file Deployment in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp-classic

I have some *.vbs files on server  \inetpub\wwwroot\ABC.VBS .Which will send mail to user.
How do I run  or configure them ? So that it will start sending Mail to user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an ASP script on your server which will send an email to a user (for instance once they have completed a form requesting the file) then something like this will send the mail as an attachment:

```
<%
Set eMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
eMail.Subject="Sending requested files"
eMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
eMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
eMail.TextBody="Please see attachment for requested file"
eMail.AddAttachment "\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC.VBS"
eMail.Send
set eMail=nothing
%>
```